# Printing Glossary entries without ever referencing them in your work

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, nomenclature

I am yet to create my list of abbreviations and symbols using the package Glossary. Since i am done with my thesis, i wont be referencing the glossary entries in the text where i used them. Is it possible that with the glossary package i can still print my abbreviations without ever referencing them?

Answer (score 5):

Is there a really good reasen why you want to use the obsolete package glossary? If not, I would suggest switching to the newer package glossaries. Using this package you can add entries, that were never referenced in you text, to your list of abbreviations using the following command.

```
\glsadd{}
```

Comment: I had challenges using \glsadd{}, perhaps i wasnt using it the right way. But i figured putting \glsaddall after \begin{document} but before \printglossary works fine!!

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to using `\glsaddall` is to use `\printunsrtglossary` provided by the extension package [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra). This command simply iterates over all defined entries (in the order in which they were defined) for the given glossary.

Example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[abbreviations,symbols,style=index]{glossaries-extra}

\newabbreviation{html}{HTML}{hypertext markup language}
\newabbreviation{ssi}{SSI}{server-side includes}
\newabbreviation{xml}{XML}{extensible markup language}

\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={cardinality of the set $\mathcal{S}$}]
 {cardS}{$|\mathcal{S}|$}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={imaginary number $\sqrt{-1}$}]{i}{$i$}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={pi}]{pi}{$\pi$}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={a set}]{S}{$\mathcal{S}$}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={universal set}]{U}{$\mathcal{U}$}

\begin{document}
\printunsrtglossary[type=abbreviations]
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols]

\end{document}
```

Build sequence (where the source file is called `mydoc.tex`):

```
latex mydoc
```

(or `pdflatex` or `xelatex` or `lualatex`)

Page 1:

[image: image of list of abbreviations]

Page 2:

[image: image of list of symbols]

Compare with:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[abbreviations,symbols,style=index,nonumberlist]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\newabbreviation{html}{HTML}{hypertext markup language}
\newabbreviation{ssi}{SSI}{server-side includes}
\newabbreviation{xml}{XML}{extensible markup language}

\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={cardinality of the set $\mathcal{S}$}]
 {cardS}{$|\mathcal{S}|$}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={imaginary number $\sqrt{-1}$}]{i}{$i$}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={pi}]{pi}{$\pi$}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={a set}]{S}{$\mathcal{S}$}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={universal set}]{U}{$\mathcal{U}$}

\glsaddall

\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=abbreviations]
\printglossary[type=symbols]

\end{document}
```

Build process:

```
latex mydoc
makeglossaries mydoc
latex mydoc
```

### Pros and Cons

- `\printunsrtglossary` doesn't require any external tools so no modification is needed to the build sequence.
- `\printglossary` requires an indexing application to sort and collate and then another LaTeX run.
- `\printunsrtglossary` doesn't sort, so you need to make sure you define the terms in the order you want them to appear in the glossary.
- `\glsaddall` adds the same number to the location list of every entry, so you need `nonumberlist` to hide the location lists, since they're not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution is the following template

```
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{something}
{
    name=somthing,
    description={an un known thing}
}
    

\title{my glossary}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
 
\glsaddall
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

" \glsaddall " will show all glossary items even the ones that are not referred to within the document text.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thank you @Mensch